# Jenkins - Environment Variables - Location not found?

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

So I have a number of Jenkins jobs where within a job I need to specify a variable (COMMON_DATA_HOME). I give it the full Windows path to that variable but the job keeps failing (see error image), it seems to be looking within the jobs own location for the variable path but that's not what I've set in the environmental variable so I'm not sure why its looking there or how I can get it to locate outside the build path.

[image]

[image]

Run build and the job should be successful and copy what its needs to from the Common location but it doesn't.

Comment: Almost looks like your path is included in a relative way but all backslashes are gone, so I would guess Jenkins tries to escape characters preceded with backslashes. Try double backslashes or even forward slashes in your environment variable.

Comment: You were right, changing it to forward slashes worked. Many thanks!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the variable to forward slashes worked. So initial variable 'COMMON_DATA_HOME=C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.jenkins\workspace\common-pf-test\Common' is now 'COMMON_DATA_HOME=/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/.jenkins/workspace/common-pf-test/Common'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).